# Vue JS: Cannot get input value in async method

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

What I want to achieve is to update the value of a hidden input on radio change. But when I submit the form the async method that is being called reads null as hidden input's value.
Here is my code:

The radio buttons and the hidden input:

```
<input type="radio" id="idiotis" name="expertiserd" value="Idi" @change="expChanged()">
<label for="idiotis">Idi</label>
<input type="radio" id="prof" name="expertiserd" value="Epag" @change="expChanged()">
 <label for="prof">Epag</label>
<input v-model="field.value" style=" border-radius:8px;border-width:1px; display:none" :name="field.name" class="form-control" type="text" id="cf-name" placeholder="" autocomplete="off">
```

This is the `expChanged` method:

```
expChanged(){
            document.querySelector('input[name="expertise"]').value = document.querySelector('input[name="expertiserd"]:checked').value;
}
```

And here is the async sendMessage function that is being called when the form is submitted:

```
async sendMessage() { 
            let formIsNotValid = false;
            this.fields.forEach(f => {
                if (f.required && f.value.length === 0) { //Here I get the error despite that I have already set the value of the hidden input with expChanged function
                    formIsNotValid = true;
                    f.hasValidationError = true;
                }
           ............
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would try to not mix a Vue approach with pure JS approach, i.e. don't use `document.querySelector()` when using Vue. Then you can just assign variable values:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      radioValue: null,
      textValue: null
    };
  },
  methods: {
    expChanged(){
      this.textValue = this.radioValue
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <input type="radio" value="Idi" @change="expChanged()" v-model="radioValue">
  <label for="idiotis">Idi</label>
  <input type="radio" value="Epag" @change="expChanged()" v-model="radioValue">
  <label for="prof">Epag</label>
  <input v-model="textValue" class="form-control" type="text">
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.7.10/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/v-calendar"></script>
```